# "30 day span", "30-day span", or "30 days span"

Tags: hyphenation, open-vs-closed-vs-hyphenated

As in, "for each 30-day span, a late fee will be charged." I think the hyphenated version looks best, but is there some sort of authoritative word on that in a style guide?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but can you rephrase this? ie. "Every 30 days, a late fee will be charged."

Answer (score 5):

Style guides sometimes say different things. They are authoritative only for the people to whom they're addressed. That said, I don't see how anyone could object to *30-day span*. The hyphen between *30* and *span* shows they are to be read together adjectivally, and the singular follows naturally from *each*.

Comment: Let's hope nobody writes a 'Universal Style Guide' then. Or does a better job than most of the others.

Comment: Units used in 'quantified descriptors' are usually given in the singular (_a ten mile hike_; _a four minute egg_). A nine days' wonder (/ nine-day wonder) is an allowed exception. Hyphens are being dropped more and more where they aren't needed for clarification, but _30-day span_ hasn't been labelled less acceptable than _30 day span_ yet, as far as I know.

Comment: I was thinking more of style guides for particular organisations, rather than publications like the excellent MWDEU.

Comment: I agree that a *30-day span* seems unimpeachable.  It’s how I would write it and how I would prefer to see it written.